# Use column from outer sql statement in function call without OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql-server

This code works OK but I have SQL2005 with compatibility level 80 so I can't use it.

With what should I substitute `OUTER APPLY` in order to use `t.Parameters` column as a parameter to function?

```
DECLARE @task TABLE
(
    ActionTaskId BIGINT,
    [Parameters] VARCHAR(512)
)

INSERT INTO @task
SELECT 1, '{"A":"#FFFFFF","B":"#000000"}' UNION
SELECT 2, '{"A":"#EEEEEE","B":"#000000"}'

SELECT *, OA1.Val 
FROM @task AS t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[parseJSON](t.[Parameters]) AS pj WHERE pj.Name='A') OA1
```

Required output:

```
ActionTaskId | Val
----------------
1 | #FFFFFF     
2 | #EEEEEE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have small amount of data, there is workaround (not efficient):

```
SELECT *
    , 'A' = [dbo].[fsParseJSON](t.[Parameters], 'A') 
    , 'B' = [dbo].[fsParseJSON](t.[Parameters], 'B')
FROM @task AS t
```

where scalar function looks like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fsParseJSON 
(
    @Json varchar(4000), @Name VARCHAR(128)
)
RETURNS varchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result varchar(128)

    SELECT @Result = [pj].[StringValue]
    FROM [dbo].[parseJSON](@Json) AS pj
    WHERE [pj].[Name] = @Name

    RETURN @Result

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
    , (
        SELECT MAX (pj.Val)
        FROM [dbo].[parseJSON](t.[Parameters]) AS pj
        WHERE pj.Name='A'
    )
FROM @task AS t
```

BTW, could you show what is inside parseJSON function? Just interesting.

Comment: Great stuff from https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/

Comment: Doesn't works. `"Incorrect syntax near '.'."` I think it is complaining about `(t.[Parameters])`

Comment: Remember it's `SQL2005` with compatibility level set to `SQL2000`

Comment: Unfortunately true. I tried it on test db. It seems that in SQL2000 the only possibility is to use cycle. =(